# Different between id and name property in MVC 4 for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a MVC 4 project. I have a text and a button. I want whenever click on the button if text is empty dispaly an alert with jQuery.

View:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#send").on("click", function (e) {
                var m = $("#txt1").val();
                if (m == "") {
                    alert(m);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
         });
    });
</script>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="txt1" />
    <button type="submit" id="send">send</button>
}
```

But not work. If I change text like following it worked!

```
@Html.TextBox("txt1")
or
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
```

Why in "**@Html.TextBox("txt1")**" uses **name** and in "**<input type="text" id="txt1" />**" uses **id**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
$("#send").on("click", function (e) {
            var m = $("input[name='txt1']").val();
            if (m == "") {
                alert(m);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `validate` your `form` by `input name` then use `[name="txt1"]` not `#txt1` like,

```
var m = $("input[name='txt1']").val();
```

**Full code**

```
$(function () {
     $("#send").on("click", function (e) {
           var m = $("input[name='txt1']").val();
           if (m == "") {
               alert(m);
               e.preventDefault();
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: There may be one reason `form` need the `name` of its `elements` when `submit` and `id` must be `unique`. Also you can pass `other attributes` in `Textbox()` See [InputExtensions:Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery `#` is used for selecting elements by `id`, that's why your 2nd code works.

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />

var m = $("#txt1").val();
```

The rendered `html` for `@Html.TextBox("txt1")` will be :-

```
<input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given "id" attribute into your input type instead of that you have just Given name like,

```
 <input type="text" name="txt1" />
```

and you have written jquery code as,

```
$("#txt1").val()
```

then How it will detect the DOM element with the id="txt1"?

for that you have to use code as,

```
$("#send").on("click", function (e) {
           var m = $("input[name='txt1']").val();
           if (m == "") {
               alert(m);
               e.preventDefault();
           }
     });
```

And for you specification when you will use the Razor syntax as,

```
@Html.TextBox("txt1")
```

then it will Create a DOM element that is having "name","id" & other attributes as well,